# Convert Groupedby object to DataFrame or series, without operation

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I am a beginner in Python and have got an issue which I cannot seem to solve.

I have grouped my DataFrame based on two columns. On some of them I have performed an operation like `.mean()` or `.std()`, from which the result becomes a Series. 
These I can use in my formula.

However, I also need the groups to become a Series or DataFrame without an operation. When I print the group with:

```
print(object.apply(list))
```

the result is the desired layout.

However how do I convert these GroupedBy objects so it will become the Series or DataFrame?

I hope someone can help me.

*Thanks!!*

Answer (score 0):

To create a dataframe from a groupby :

```
# Simple count 
new_df = pandas.DataFrame({'NB' : df.groupby(['col_name1']).count()})

# groupby col1 and take the mean of col2  
new_df = pandas.DataFrame({'Mean' : df.groupby(['col_name1'])['col_name2'].mean()})
```

Comment: IMO this is not an answer to the question. OP is perfectly fine with those cases, where an aggregation function is applied to the group (`count` or `mean` etc). Besides that, these aggregation functions already return a dataframe, so I don't quite get the point of your answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you provided no sample data nor your code, so I'm not sure if I understand your problem correct.

But by grouping, you get an object containing several dataframes, "subdataframes" if you like, so the groupby object itself cannot be shown as a simple dataframe anymore. But you can iterate over it, getting the name and the subdataframes which you can print simply.
Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col': ['blue', 'red', 'blue', 'red'], 'Val1': [12, 34, 56, 78],'Val2': [42, 53, 64, 75]})

    Col  Val1  Val2
0  blue    12    42
1   red    34    53
2  blue    56    64
3   red    78    75


for name, grp in df.groupby('Col'):
    print(name, grp, sep='\n', end='\n\n')
blue
    Col  Val1  Val2
0  blue    12    42
2  blue    56    64

red
   Col  Val1  Val2
1  red    34    53
3  red    78    75
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,11,(10,3)), 
columns = ['num1','num2','num3'])
df['category'] = ['a','a','a','b','b','b','b','c','c','c']
df = df[['category','num1','num2','num3']]
gb = df.groupby('category')
gb.get_group("a")
```

There are three groups for this data: a, b, c
you can use gb.get_group("a") to get the datafame for the group a